# Enable the textbox in JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

This is my problem: I'm trying to create a function in JS that if the checkbox is checked it will enable the textbox. How can I do it?
Thanks for the helps! so this is what I did.

this is my code in JS:

```
function checkLevelZone(sender, args) {
    var reVal = false;
    var retValCB = false;
    var l_CheckOffsite = $find("<%=OffSiteCheck.ClientID %>").set_checked(true);
    var l_txtOffsite = $find("<%=txtOffSite.ClientID %>");

    if (l_CheckOffsite.get_checked()) {
        l_txtOffsite.disable = true;
    } 
}
```

The function taking the checkbox and setting it to true maybe that is the problem with the syntax.

Comment: What is `$find` or `.get_checked()` ?

Comment: if the checkbox is check so go to textbox and enable it.

Comment: $find it mean that is going to find the control

Comment: can you show me how to do it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
document.getElementById("<%=OffSiteCheck.ClientID %>").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("<%=txtOffSite.ClientID %>").disabled = this.checked
}
```

Comment: what I tried to do in my function is to save the contorles checkbox and textbox and once you click on the checkbox it will enable=true the textbox. I don't understand what your function is doing please help me.

Comment: This function is creating a `change` event for your checkbox. Once you click it, it finds your control of ID `txtOffSite` and sets the `disabled` property to the condition of the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**http://jsfiddle.net/4bEX2/**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#radio1").click(function(){
        $("#textbox1").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#textbox2").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
    $("#radio2").click(function(){
        $("#textbox2").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#textbox1").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
});
```